# Reusing content of Angular ngb-tabs in multiple tabs with ngTemplateOutlet or something else

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ng-template, ng-container, ngbtab

I am using Angular ng-tabset to render some tabs. My ngb-tab looks somewhat like:

```
<ngb-tab id="mytabs">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        <div data-locator="xxxe">yyy</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
```

which works fine. But I have a couple of other tabs also in this template where I want the same content rendered. so, for the purpose of re-usability, I was trying to move the contents of the tab separate and use it's reference in each tab where I want that rendered. I am not sure how to do it. I tried putting it inside a separate `<ng-template>` as:

```
<ng-template #testing>
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        <div data-locator="xxxe">yyy</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </ng-template>
<ng-template
```

and under tab, where I need this rendered, I try to call it as:

```
<ngb-tab id="mytabs">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="testing"></ng-container>    // referring the #testing above
</ngb-tab>

OR:

<ngb-tab id="mytabs">
    <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="testing"></ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
```

But my tabs are not rendered. Maybe its wrong approach or I am missing something. Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to achieve? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not nesting the ng-templates and use them with different ids, then inserting them under ngb-tab separately like this:

```
<ng-template ngbTabTitle #testTitle>
    <div data-locator="xxxe">yyy</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template ngbTabContent #testContent>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</ng-template>
<ngb-tab id="mytabs">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="testTitle"></ng-container>    
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="testContent"></ng-container>
</ngb-tab>
```

Comment: That is how I started first, but then I felt it would be better to have the title and content under one template id and just refer that one single id. I wanted to avoid creating two ( one for each) and then referring each. Is it possible to do it that way or its not possible at all?

Comment: Honestly, I am not very familiar with the ngb library, my assumption was that nesting the ng-templates could cause anomalies while using ngbTabTitle and ngbTabContent directives.

Comment: OK, I just realized that you are calling them as `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="testTitle"></ng-container>. and not ng-template. The problem that I ran into is that when I try to use *ngTemplateOutlet with ng-container as you have indicated above, it does not render the tab at all, whereas when I put the whole content from the template inline without using `ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet`, tabs do get rendered. so, `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet` is not rendering tabs

Comment: That is rather interesting because by specification ngTemplateOutlet is used with ng-container : https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet.

Comment: I think you can create a component just containing the ng-templates (ngbTabTitle and ngbTabContent ) and put it inside <ngb-tab> as a workaround to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understand your question right.  For re-usability of templates you can create you own components. For re-usability of logic you can create services.

```
<ngb-tab id="mytabs">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        <my-xyz-comp data-locator="xxxe"></my-xyz-comp>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <my-xyz-comp data-locator="aaaa"></my-xyz-comp>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
```